# How to create Datatable Editable dynamically using API in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I did work in creating simple Datatable using API in javaScript. Now I want to create Editable Datatable so that I can edit every field on spot. I am using a Bootstrap theme [Mplify](https://themeforest.net/item/mplify-bootstrap-4-admin-dashboard-template/22388211). The problem is that when I load the page and make a static Datatable code in HTML file then Datatable with Editable fields creates correctly. But when I create it dynamically then **TypeError: c is undefined** and Datatable doesn't work correctly.

Here is my code:

```
<button id="addToTable" class="btn btn-primary m-b-15" type="button">
  <i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add row
</button>
<div class="table-responsive" id="tableOneDiv">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover js-basic-example dataTable table-custom" id="addrowExample">
    <thead id="theadId">

    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyId">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And this is the javaScript part:

```
$detailOne = '';
$detailTwo = '';
$theadId = $('#theadId');
$tbodyId = $('#tbodyId');

$('#theadId').html('');
$('#tbodyId').html('');

$detailOne = '<tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Action</th></tr>';
// this is the API call
$.get(api, function(data) {
  $.each(data.BomKits, function(j, one) {
    $detailTwo += '<tr class="gradeA">';
    $detailTwo += '<td>'+one.Name+'</td>';
    $detailTwo += '<td>'+one.Class+'</td>';
    $detailTwo += '<td>'+one.School+'</td>';
    $detailTwo += '<td class="actions"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-editing m-r-5 button-save" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Save" hidden><i class="icon-drawer" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-editing button-discard" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Discard" hidden><i class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default m-r-5 button-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default button-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="icon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>'
    $detailTwo += '</tr>';
  });

  $theadId.append($detailOne);
  $tbodyId.append($detailTwo);

  // this is from jquery-datatable.js
  setTimeout(function() {
    var addRowTable = {
      options: {
          addButton: "#addToTable",
          table: "#addrowExample",
          dialog: {}
      },
      initialize: function() {
          this.setVars().build().events()
      },
      setVars: function() {
          return this.$table = $(this.options.table), this.$addButton = $(this.options.addButton), this.dialog = {}, this.dialog.$wrapper = $(this.options.dialog.wrapper), this.dialog.$cancel = $(this.options.dialog.cancelButton), this.dialog.$confirm = $(this.options.dialog.confirmButton), this
      },
      build: function() {
          return this.datatable = this.$table.DataTable({
              aoColumns: [null, null, null, {
                  bSortable: !1
              }],
          }), window.dt = this.datatable, this
      },
      events: function() {
          var object = this;
          return this.$table.on("click", "button.button-save", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault(), object.rowSave($(this).closest("tr"))
          }).on("click", "button.button-discard", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault(), object.rowCancel($(this).closest("tr"))
          }).on("click", "button.button-edit", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault(), object.rowEdit($(this).closest("tr"))
          }).on("click", "button.button-remove", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
              swal({
                  title: "Are you sure?",
                  text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                  type: "warning",
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  confirmButtonColor: "#dc3545",
                  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                  closeOnConfirm: false
              }, function () {
                  object.rowRemove($row)
                  swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
              });
          }), this.$addButton.on("click", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault(), object.rowAdd()
          }), this.dialog.$cancel.on("click", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault(), $.magnificPopup.close()
          }), this
      },
      rowAdd: function() {
          this.$addButton.attr({
              disabled: "disabled"
          });
          var actions, data, $row;
          actions = ['<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-editing button-save" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Save" hidden><i class="icon-drawer" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>', '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-editing button-discard" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Discard" hidden><i class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>', '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default button-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>', '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default button-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="icon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'].join(" "), data = this.datatable.row.add(["", "", "", actions]), ($row = this.datatable.row(data[0]).nodes().to$()).addClass("adding").find("td:last").addClass("actions"), this.rowEdit($row), this.datatable.order([0, "asc"]).draw()
      },
      rowCancel: function($row) {
          var $actions, data;
          $row.hasClass("adding") ? this.rowRemove($row) : (($actions = $row.find("td.actions")).find(".button-discard").tooltip("hide"), $actions.get(0) && this.rowSetActionsDefault($row), data = this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).data(), this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).data(data), this.handleTooltip($row), this.datatable.draw())
      },
      rowEdit: function($row) {
          var data, object = this;
          data = this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).data(), $row.children("td").each(function(i) {
              var $this = $(this);
              $this.hasClass("actions") ? object.rowSetActionsEditing($row) : $this.html('<input type="text" class="form-control input-block" value="' + data[i] + '"/>')
          })
      },
      rowSave: function($row) {
          var $actions, object = this,
              values = [];
          $row.hasClass("adding") && (this.$addButton.removeAttr("disabled"), $row.removeClass("adding")), values = $row.find("td").map(function() {
              var $this = $(this);
              return $this.hasClass("actions") ? (object.rowSetActionsDefault($row), object.datatable.cell(this).data()) : $.trim($this.find("input").val())
          }), ($actions = $row.find("td.actions")).find(".button-save").tooltip("hide"), $actions.get(0) && this.rowSetActionsDefault($row), this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).data(values), this.handleTooltip($row), this.datatable.draw()
      },
      rowRemove: function($row) {
          $row.hasClass("adding") && this.$addButton.removeAttr("disabled"), this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).remove().draw()
      },
      rowSetActionsEditing: function($row) {
          $row.find(".on-editing").removeAttr("hidden"), $row.find(".on-default").attr("hidden", !0)
      },
      rowSetActionsDefault: function($row) {
          $row.find(".on-editing").attr("hidden", !0), $row.find(".on-default").removeAttr("hidden")
      },
      handleTooltip: function($row) {
          $row.find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
      }
    };

    addRowTable.initialize()
  }, 3000);
});
```

I don't know why this problem happening. Anyone know then please help me.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of the error you are getting.

Comment: @NiK648 https://imgur.com/S3AVFZk "error" Line names may conflict the code which is above mentioned. But you can see the errors.